# i had a problem with the alert message

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, dynamic-visualforce

```
<apex:page standardController="opportunity" rendered="{!opportunity.stagename='Offer'}">
<script type="text/javascript">
{
window.alert("Please update the field 'Specific Pricing'. Veuillez mettre à jour le champ 'Prix Spécifique'");
}
</script>
</apex:page>
```

it is showing the alert message every time when the stage is equal to offer .

i need alert message in the way, when the stage is changed to offer.how can i do it????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a validation rule for that, not a JS alert in an embedded visualforce page. You'd probably want this to hit also when Opportunity is modified on database level... and don't forget that VF pages are invisible on edit page so I'm not sure how you wanted to get it to work... inline edits probably?

Read about val. rules in Setup in the "help for this page". Something with condition like that might be close to what you're after?

```
ISCHANGED(StageName) && ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Offer') && ISBLANK(Specific_Pricing__c)
```

That's pretty much the only time you'll see "old and new" value (let's ignore triggers ;)). A VF page will see the saved state so "Offer" and nothing else.

---

Edit: ok, so you need a warning message, not an error... You will have to use a workflow rule or trigger that will hit on condition similar to what I've written. There's no easy way for the embedded VF page to know what "just changed" (there's a trickier way where you could query for the changes in the Stage history in last minute for example but that might be painful to fine-tune).

It's your call what field you'll be setting, maybe just a checkbox called "Pricing warning"?

Once you have the workflow rule (remember to activate it) change your page's rendering condition to look for this checkbox = true. And maybe add a "Dismiss" button on that page that will clear the checkbox.

If you still want to try querying for Stage changes - something like this might be a good start:

```
SELECT CreatedById, OpportunityId, StageName, SystemModstamp
FROM OpportunityHistory
WHERE OpportunityId = :opportunityId AND CreatedById = :UserInfo.getUserId()
ORDER BY SystemModstamp DESC
```

---

Edit #2

Something like that should get you started. It clears the checkbox as soon as the page finishes loading. It's frowned upon in the Salesforce security reviews (and rightly so) because viewing some page shouldn't have side-effects like database update... But if you want to display it only once I'm not sure what else we can do...

```
<apex:page standardController="opportunity" extensions="MyOppController" rendered="{!opportunity.pricing_warning__c}" action="{!clearTheCheckbox}">
<script type="text/javascript">
{
window.alert("Please update the field 'Specific Pricing'. Veuillez mettre à jour le champ 'Prix Spécifique'");
}
</script>
</apex:page>

public class MyOppController{
    Opportunity opp;
    public MyOppController(Apexpages.StandardController sc){
        opp = (Opportunity) sc.getRecord();
    }

    public void clearTheCheckbox(){
        if(opp.pricing_warning__c){
            opp.pricing_warning__c = false;
            update opp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in validation rule we will get error message,but in this the user has to just see the warning and he can be able to save the record .its just like a warning message .i dont thinks so we can get warning message through validation rule

Comment: Can you use a workflow rule maybe that would be setting a field on Opportunity when this condition is met? And another to clear the warning when they do enter or move away from Offer stage?

Comment: i had tried that one with two record types as one with vf and another one without vf.It behaviour is same .when ever the opportunity is equal to offer it is shows warning.if he edit or non edit the satge.suppose satge value is different ,any it is not showing any warning

Comment: hi i am following your workflow procedure .i am struck in dismiss button how can i link to work flow .can you explain in detail

Comment: Would you like to have a button or let them untick the checkbox manually (maybe on the Opportunity page itself, not on the VF page)?

Comment: Any way not manual ,automatically take the dismiss button

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:page standardController="opportunity">
<script type="text/javascript">
{
window.alert("Please update the field 'Specific Pricing'. Veuillez mettre à jour le champ 'Prix Spécifique'");
}
</script>
</apex:page>
```

write a workflow :as

ISCHANGED(StageName) && ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Offer')

make a field update as record type with vf.

write another workflow that

(NOT(ISCHANGED(StageName)) && NOT(ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Offer')))||(NOT(ISCHANGED(StageName)) && (ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Offer')))||((ISCHANGED(StageName)) && NOT(ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Offer')))

make a field update as recordtype with out vf

Comment: The second workflow needs something to fire, they aren't triggered by just viewing the data. I think you'll continue to show the warning until somebody makes an update to the Opp.